# Paypal API and Wordpress

Tags: user-roles, paypal

Hi does anybody know where i can find a PayPal API tutorial that can help to point me in the right direction, What im needing is something that when payment is verified by paypal it bounces through some code to update_user_meta and also a few fields in a custom table in wp database.

Information that i can find via google is pretty vague in what im requiring.

regards
Martin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try working through the source code of a plugin such as [PayPal Framework](http://xavisys.com/wordpress-plugins/paypal-framework/).

From your question, the WP side is fairly trivial, but you should study general PayPal tutorials to understand the API, for example,  here's the first search result from Google for PayPal API tutorial: [Using PayPal's IPN with PHP](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/using-paypals-instant-payment-notification-with-php/)

Also some additional helpful info can be found [here](https://www.paypal.com/ph/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_additional-payment-integration-outside).

Comment: That will teach me to read all the way through the net tuts tutorial, i looked at that before and thought it wasnt for me, well actually after reading it thoroughly it covers just about all i need to know.. marked as answered, many thanks.